# Specifying color with ggplot2 in R for stacked graph in which the same stacked section bearing different ranking across panels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm trying to apply specific colors for `AMATA` `CHEAL` `DIGSA` `SETSP` `SOLPT` and `Others` (plant species code) on the following graph. The reason is that I have three data sets for three years and I need to use the same color for the same species on all three graphs.

[image]

Here is one year of data

```
data <-
structure(list(Rot = c("2-year", "2-year", "2-year", "2-year", 
"2-year", "2-year", "2-year", "2-year", "2-year", "2-year", "2-year", 
"2-year", "3-year", "3-year", "3-year", "3-year", "3-year", "3-year", 
"3-year", "3-year", "3-year", "3-year", "3-year", "3-year", "4-year", 
"4-year", "4-year", "4-year", "4-year", "4-year", "4-year", "4-year", 
"4-year", "4-year", "4-year", "4-year"), Herb = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("conv", "low"), class = "factor"), species = c("AMATA", 
"CHEAL", "DIGSA", "Others", "SETSP", "SOLPT", "AMATA", "CHEAL", 
"DIGSA", "Others", "SETSP", "SOLPT", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "DIGSA", 
"Others", "SETSP", "SOLPT", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "DIGSA", "Others", 
"SETSP", "SOLPT", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "DIGSA", "Others", "SETSP", 
"SOLPT", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "DIGSA", "Others", "SETSP", "SOLPT"
), m.adens = c(2197.4261496, 1192.447112475, 0, 18.7667669625, 
104.09825015, 17.0234713875, 4660.7003427875, 3764.4214453625, 
16.6470464875, 84.80790515, 492.4442869375, 16.9923696125, 2247.36022525833, 
2307.16391086667, 0, 73.9299205416667, 262.936172, 186.0226796, 
5495.27938680833, 9735.14487680833, 10.909839225, 360.878508416667, 
2322.27422545833, 126.091509308333, 4969.48674180625, 1711.9130538625, 
205.3436674125, 494.4264206125, 1254.0715623, 124.4742832125, 
3825.15189476875, 3038.0082425, 181.47105726875, 163.71343195, 
3379.4791432, 41.786807975)), .Names = c("Rot", "Herb", "species", 
"m.adens"), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

For coloring, I used

```
    ggplot(data, aes(x=Herb, y=m.adens, fill=species))+   geom_bar(stat="identity")+  
 scale_fill_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 6, name = "Set1"),
         breaks= c("AMATA","CHEAL","DIGSA","SETSP","SOLPT","Others"))
```

With this code, colors were applied to the correct species. I tried to specify colors by changing `breaks` to `labels`. But, using `labels`would not color the species correctly.

`labels` only arranges color arbitrarily in the legend panel which does not match each stacked section. Please see what I did wrong with my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for facetting?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Herb, y = m.adens, fill = species)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 6, name = "Set1"),
    breaks = c("AMATA", "CHEAL", "DIGSA", "SETSP", "SOLPT", "Others")) +
  facet_wrap( ~ Rot)
```

[image]

Now, to get the colouring right, `species` needs to be coerced to factor giving the levels in the correct order:

```
species_names <- c("AMATA", "CHEAL", "DIGSA", "SETSP", "SOLPT", "Others")
data$species <- factor(data$species, levels = rev(species_names))

ggplot(data, aes(x = Herb, y = m.adens, fill = species)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 6, name = "Set1")),
    breaks = species_names) +
  facet_wrap( ~ Rot) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Please note that `rev()` is used two times here. The first time `rev()` is used to put `AMATA` as last factor level so it is plotted at the bottom of the stacked bar. The second time it is used to reverse the color scale so that colors do match again to the species.

Comment: Thank you for your time and detailed explanation. Your explanation is helpful for my other coding effort too. Have a nice day.

Comment: @LittleBee I'm glad you find my explanations helpful.